# Why can't the Shtei HaLechem be baked on Shavuoth?

Tags: shavuos, shtei-halechem

In [Avoth 5:5](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Pirkei_Avot.5.5?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he) we learn that one of the 10 miracles in the Temple was that the Shtei HaLechem - the 2 breads brought on Shavuoth and eaten by the Cohanim - were never found to be invalid:

> עֲשָׂרָה נִסִּים נַעֲשׂוּ לַאֲבוֹתֵינוּ בְּבֵית הַמִּקְדָּשׁ ... וְלֹא נִמְצָא פְסוּל בָּעֹמֶר וּבִשְׁתֵּי הַלֶּחֶם וּבְלֶחֶם הַפָּנִים,‏

The Bartenura explains that since they **could not be baked on Yom Tov**, had they been invalid there would be no way to replace them:

> **וְלֹא נִמְצָא פְסוּל בָּעֹמֶר וּבִשְׁתֵּי הַלֶּחֶם וּבְלֶחֶם הַפָּנִים.** שֶׁאִם הָיָה נִמְצָא בָּהֶם פְּסוּל קֹדֶם מִצְוָתָן לֹא הָיָה אֶפְשָׁר לְהַקְרִיב אֲחֵרִים תַּחְתָּם. שֶׁהָעֹמֶר נִקְצַר בַּלַּיְלָה וְלֹא הָיוּ מַרְבִּים לִקְצֹר. **וּשְׁתֵּי הַלֶּחֶם נֶאֱפִים מֵעֶרֶב יוֹם טוֹב וְאֵין אֲפִיָּתָן דּוֹחָה יוֹם טוֹב**. וְכֵן לֶחֶם הַפָּנִים נֶאֱפָה מֵעֶרֶב שַׁבָּת‏

I'm wondering why the Shtei-HaLechem couldn't be baked on Yom Tov, why are they different from any other bread that may be baked on Yom Tov?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Pesachim 47a](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.47a.6?lang=bi) (with **translation** and elucidation from Sefaria):

> שאני התם דאמר קרא לכם לכם ולא לגבוה
>
> The Gemara answers: **It is different there**, in the case of the two loaves, **as the verse says**: “No kind of labor shall be done on them, save that which every man must eat, that only may be done **for you**” (Exodus 12:16). This indicates that it is permitted to cook and bake only “**for you**,” i.e., for human consumption, **and not for the** One **above**, namely for the Temple service.

It's worth noting that this is actually a matter of dispute. R. Shimon b. Gamliel allows one to bake the *shtei halechem* on Shavuot itself. As the gemara [continues](https://www.sefaria.org/Pesachim.47a.7?lang=bi):

> ולרבן שמעון בן גמליאל דאמר משום רבי שמעון בן הסגן דוחה את יום טוב מאי איכא למימר סבר לה כאבא שאול דאמר לכם לכם ולא לגוים
>
> The Gemara asks: **And according to Rabban Shimon ben Gamliel, who said in the name of Rabbi Shimon, son of the deputy** High Priest, that baking the shewbread **overrides the Festival, what can be said**? How does he understand the term: For you? The Gemara answers: **He holds in accordance with the opinion of Abba Shaul, who said** that this verse should be understood in the following manner: Cooking and baking are permitted **for you, and not for gentiles**; for the sake of the Temple service, however, they are permitted.

Comment: OK, but why is the considered _for the One above, namely for the Temple service_ when it's eaten (completely) by the Cohanim?